# Why isn't X2Go Server in the main Ubuntu repository?

Tags: repository, x2go

While the X2Go client (package "x2goclient") can be downloaded from the main Ubuntu repository; this is not true for the X2Go server. One needs to get it from a different repository by doing the following (according to http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

I understand X2Go has been around for some time. How come it is not entirely available from the official repo, and the server component is available only as a PPA?

Comment: Because it's not in Debian. I can't find any source about why it is not in Debian but the answer is probably "because there is nobody willing and able to do the packaging work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As fkraiem says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723058/why-isnt-x2go-server-in-the-main-ubuntu-repository/723084#comment1069452_723058), it's because nobody packaged it for Debian. And in Debian, it seems a few people expressed in intent to package it, but never followed through. See [Debian bug report 465821](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=465821) for more information (it's been sitting around since 2008).

Comment: Got it. It is nevertheless puzzling that some guys took over the job of packaging the client side, but left untouched the server side, without which you can do very little. X2Go is then in a sort of "half-packaged" state. Of course, this is not a criticism to the people who contributed with the client side, to which we all are thankful. It's just curiosity about an abnormal state for the program.